# How to draw a DFA for given language?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, dfa

Give a finite state diagram for a DFA that accepts any word in the language $L = \{w \mid w \in \{a, b\}^* \text{ and }w \text{ alternates } a\text{'s and }b\text{’s and has an even number of }b\text{’s}\}$.

My attempt: I am having problem on how to deal with the even part of b.

Comment: Just to clarify, does a string in the language have to start with $a$, or would you consider the string $bab$ to be in the language (since the $a$s and $b$s alternate and it has an even number of $b$s)?

Comment: It can start with either one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the strings must be of the form $ababab\dotsm$, and also there must be 0, 2, 4, 6, ... $b$s, begin with four states, each of which "remembers" the input so far:

- $q_0$: just saw an $a$ and have seen an even number of $b$s so far,
- $r_0$: just saw a $b$ and have seen an odd number of $b$s so far,
- $q_1$: just saw an $a$ and have seen an odd number of $b$s so far,
- $r_1$: just saw a $b$ and have seen an even number of $b$s so far.

Then, it's clear that these states will have transitions in a cycle, with transitions:

- $\delta(q_0, b) = r_0$
- $\delta(r_0, a) = q_1$
- $\delta(q_1, b) = r_1$
- $\delta(r_1, a) = q_0$

and the other possibilities will either be undefined or lead to a trap state, depending on what model of a DFA you're accustomed to using. Now make a new start state $s$, with $\delta(s, a) = q_0$ (since you've just seen an $a$ and have no $b$s yet), and, for similar reasons, define $\delta(s, b) = r_0$. I'll leave it to you to decide which (two) of the states in the cycle of four states should be final.

There are systematic ways to do this kind of *product DFA*, but in this case, it's no simpler than this *ad hoc* construction.